# Convert Schema.SObjectfield to string

Tags: sobject, string, sobjectfield

I have a List of Schema.SObjectfield and I want to convert it to String.

I am getting below error.

```
System.JSONException: Apex Type unsupported in JSON: Schema.SObjectField
```

Here is my approach.

```
  public string jsondata{get;set;}




  List<Schema.SObjectField> fieldschema = new List<Schema.SObjectField>();

    for(Schema.SObjectField sfield : fieldMap.Values()) {
       fieldschema.add(sfield);
    }

     jsondata = JSON.serialize(fieldschema);
 jsonstring = (List<jsonvalue>) System.JSON.deserialize(jsondata , List<jsonvalue>.class);
```

can someone please let me know where is wrong in my approach or how to handle it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't serialize SObjectField, as the error says, but it's easy to get the value as a String:

```
public string jsondata{get;set;}
List<String> fieldschema = new List<String>();

for(Schema.SObjectField sfield : fieldMap.Values()) {
   fieldschema.add(''+sfield);
}

jsondata = JSON.serialize(fieldschema);
```

You can also use the keyset values:

```
fieldSchema = new List<String>(fieldMap.keySet());
```

Comment: I am getting this error with this code after execution in runtime.                  System.JSONException: Expected ABV_GenerateXMLs.jsonvalue but found "Id" at [line:1, column:2]
Error is in expression '{!getFieldsPicklist}' in page generatexmls: Class.System.JSON.deserialize: line 15, column 1